# how to open dustjs template with extension '.dust'

Tags: dust.js

I have some files with extension '.dust' which is clearly DustJs templates. Somehow I managed to call them in my HTML code but it throws error. So can somebody tell me the step by step procedure to see what it is in .dust files that I have?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried or searched so far and give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have done some rubbish thing ....need step by step proc from scratch as the official site has nothing clear. It seems confusing. Please help